# input (a+b)**2 , output a*a + a*b + b*a + b*b

Tags: python-3.x

Is it possible to calculate `(a+b)**2` such that the output is `a*a + a*b + b*a + b*b` (instead of `a*a + 2*a*b + b*b`)?

I tried it with:

```
a, b = sympy.symbols('a, b')

expr = sympy.expand((a + b)**2)
```

but then the output is `a*a + 2*a*b + b*b`.

Answer (score 3):

Make your symbols non-commutative:

```
>>> a, b = sympy.symbols('a, b', commutative=False)
>>> sympy.expand((a + b)**2)
a*b + a**2 + b*a + b**2
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot:)!